# Append repeated text using sed or awk?

Tags: text, sed, awk, transformation

I have the following config file:

```
servers = (
  {
    host = "localhost";
    ...
    timeout = 5;
  },
  {
    host = "127.0.0.1";
    ...
    timeout = 0;
  },
  {
    host = "example.com";
    ...
    timeout = 99;
  }  
);
```

I want to append "index" setting at the end of each section so the config look like this:

```
servers = (
  {
    host = "localhost";
    ...
    timeout = 5;
    index = 1;
  },
  {
    host = "127.0.0.1";
    ...
    timeout = 0;
    index = 2;
  },
  {
    host = "example.com";
    ...
    timeout = 99;
    index = 3;
  }  
);
```

How can I do this with conventional Unix tools like *sed* or *awk*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This adds a line with `index = ...` after each line that has `timeout` as the first word.

```
awk '1;$1=="timeout"{printf "    index = %d;\n", ++i}' file
```

Comment: Thanx, it is simpler that I expected! I also tried to use regex instead of equality to make it more rovust. This regex "$1 ~ /^\s*timeout\s*/" works fine. But this regex "$1 ~ /^\s*timeout\s*\=\s*\d+\s*;/" does not match the string. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @VitalyP `$1` matches the first word. If you want the whole line, you should use `$0`, so the expression could be `$0 ~ /^[ \t]*timeout[ \t]*=[ \t]*[0-9]*[ \t]*;[ \t]*$`. Awk by default matches the entire line though, so you can write it like `awk '1;/^[ \t]*timeout[ \t]*=[ \t]*[0-9]*[ \t]*;[ \t]*$/{printf "    index = %d;\n", ++i}' file`